# Smarty: Call of unknown method 'display'

Tags: php, display, smarty3

this must be a very stupid question, but i have been searching it's answer and can't find the problem... I've got some trouble while trying to display a smarty template, i was using an older version of smarty and everything worked fine, yet i updated to smarty 3 and i got an exception, it's message saying:

> Call of unknown method 'display'.

This is my code:

**Index.php**

```
require_once './GeneralFunctions.php';

$smartyVariables = getSmartyVariablesToAssign();
tryToDisplaySmartyTemplate('Index.tpl', $smartyVariables);

function getSmartyVariablesToAssign() {
    $userAndOrPasswordError = $_GET['userAndOrPasswordError'];
    return array(
        'userAndOrPasswordError' => $userAndOrPasswordError
    );
}
```

**GeneralFunctions.php**

```
require_once './smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';

function tryToDisplaySmartyTemplate($templateName, $variablesToAssign = null) {
    try {
        $mySmarty = callSmarty();
        assignSmartyVariables($mySmarty, $variablesToAssign);
        $mySmarty->display($templateName);
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        showCatchedExceptionTraceAndMessage($exc);
    }
}

function callSmarty() {
    $mySmarty = new Smarty();
    $mySmarty->template_dir = 'smarty/templates';
    $mySmarty->compile_dir = 'smarty/templates_c';
    $mySmarty->config_dir = 'smarty/config';
    $mySmarty->cache_dir = 'smarty/cache';
    return $mySmarty;
}

function assignSmartyVariables($mySmarty, $variablesToAssign) {
    foreach ($variablesToAssign as $key => $value) {
        $mySmarty->assign($key, $value);
    }
}

function showCatchedExceptionTraceAndMessage(Exception $exc) {
    echo "Ocurrió un error desconocido, por favor, notifique al departamento de sistemas.",
    "<br>",
    "<br>",
    $exc->getTraceAsString(),
    "<br>",
    "<br>",
    $exc->getMessage();
}
```

I've been investigating, and all i know until now is the existence of a smarty method: testInstall()
Which gives the following info:

> Smarty Installation test... Testing template directory...
> C:\xampp\htdocs\develop\Registro_de_Tramites\smarty\templates is OK.
> Testing compile directory...
> C:\xampp\htdocs\develop\Registro_de_Tramites\smarty\templates_c is OK.
> Testing plugins directory...
> C:\xampp\htdocs\develop\Registro_de_Tramites\smarty\libs\plugins is
> OK. Testing cache directory...
> C:\xampp\htdocs\develop\Registro_de_Tramites\smarty\cache is OK.
> Testing configs directory...
> C:\xampp\htdocs\develop\Registro_de_Tramites\smarty\config is OK.
>
> Testing sysplugin files... FAILED: files missing from libs/sysplugins:
> smarty_internal_extension_codeframe.php,
> smarty_internal_extension_config.php,
> smarty_internal_extension_defaulttemplatehandler.php,
> smarty_internal_filter_handler.php,
> smarty_internal_function_call_handler.php,
> smarty_internal_get_include_path.php.
>
> Testing plugin files... ... OK
> Tests complete.

I've separated the only FAILED i've got from the rest. It seems libs/sysplugins folder is missing some php files, but downloading it all over again from [smarty releases](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/releases), just gives the same files i have...

To install it, i just copy libs folder into my project, inside "smarty" folder.

Hope to get some help :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it was a stupid question... by reinstalling smarty 3 it all worked, you see, it seems there was a problem with tortoiseSVN which (who knows why) didn't upload all smarty files properly the first time.

Strange though, that the files missing weren't the ones testInstall() was talking about...

Anyway, if any of you guys have the same problem, try reinstalling smarty first.